# Java Servlet req.getParameter("param") is null when querystring has 'ő' or 'ű' and if request is made by JQuery ajax

Tags: java, jquery, servlets, character-encoding

I have a very annoying problem With my Jquery based ajax live search. The search itself is working, but whenever my querystring contains 'ő' and 'ű' - only these two chars - , the value of the req.getParameter("sstring") is **null**! If the querystring does not have the mentioned chars, it returns the value successfully.
I tried all possible encodings inluding UTF-8 but settled using 8859-2.

```
    $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url: "/myApp/Protected/getStd",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=iso-8859-2",
    dataType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=iso-8859-2",
    data:"sstring="+escape(sstring)+"&options="+id+"&startrow="+startrow+"&valid="+Valid+"&notValid="+notValid+"&searchForm=1",

            async: true,
    success: function(data){
    $("#external").html(data);

    }
 })
```

I have to **highlight** that the problem only occures when the querystring is passed by Jquery. If I enter the QueryString to the browser manually the Servlet gets it properly. 
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: To avoid the obvious and red herrings: you also didn't specify a parameter with name `param` anywhere in your JS code. Don't you mean `request.getParameter("sstring")`? And did you also do it in the *actual* code? Unrelated to the problem, you should really not mix encodings or try random encodings, that's only recipe for trouble. Use the one and same throughout your webapp, preferably UTF-8 since that prepares for world domination.

Comment: Sure I did. I just meant the parameter is null. - by the way I edited the question. But good point, sorry for misleading... I just printed out the whole querystring with java and the funny thing is that the querystring looks like this: `'INFO: sstring=min%u0151&options=1&startrow=0&valid=true&notValid=true&searchForm=1'` but again `req.getParameter("sstring")` is still null. Is this a bug ?

Comment: try to escape all data, not just sstring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments on the question:

> ```
> INFO: sstring=min%u0151&options=1&startrow=0&valid=true&notValid=true&searchForm=1
> ```

The `sstring` parameter is not properly URL-encoded. You need [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) instead of [`escape()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.escape).

Answer (score 0):

Make the method POST.

`type:"POST",`

You don't say method is GET and yet pass the data as part of the body of the request. A GET request works purely based on URLs.

If you want to use GET, do this:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url: "/myApp/Protected/getStd?sstring="+escape(sstring)+"&options="+id+"&startrow="+startrow+"&valid="+Valid+"&notValid="+notValid+"&searchForm=1",
    async: true,
    success: function(data){
    $("#external").html(data);

    }
 })
```